# Can't make streaming data show in browser or terminal

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, stream

I'm trying to show my Kinesis stream in the browser, but unfortunately I can't seem to make this happen. The while loop containing the data does however print in my intellij console with the correctly.

Can I wrap this in anyway and call the stream in the return statement?

Service -

```
 public ResponseEntity getLocationData() {
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
    AmazonKinesis kinesisClient = AmazonKinesisClient.builder()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
            .withRegion(awsRegion)
            .build();

    GetRecordsRequest recordsRequest = new GetRecordsRequest();
    recordsRequest.setShardIterator(shardIterator.getShardIterator());
    recordsRequest.setLimit(1000);

    GetRecordsResult recordsResult = kinesisClient.getRecords(recordsRequest);
    while (!recordsResult.getRecords().isEmpty()) {
        recordsResult.getRecords().stream()
                .map(record -> new String(record.getData().array()))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        recordsRequest.setShardIterator(recordsResult.getNextShardIterator());
        kinesisClient.getRecords(recordsRequest);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(recordsResult);
}
```

Controller -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/request-location", method= {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity requestLocation(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String,String> form) {

    streamService.addDataToStream(form);
    streamService.buildShardIterator();
    streamService.getLocationData();
    return streamService.getLocationData();
}
```

Console output of while loop, what I expect to see in the browser.

[image: Intellij console output]

Comment: Why are you calling `getLocationData()` twice, ignoring the result of the first call?

Comment: What is `GetRecordsResult`? What JSON do you expect from serializing `recordsResult`, and why do you expect that?

Comment: GetRecordsResult is the AWS kinesis method you use to recover the data from your datastream. recordsResult is not what I would ideally be returning. I need to stream to the browser the output of the while loop, so that's what I want to return. I've added the output of the while loop

Comment: Then build a `List<String>` of those strings and return that. That will get you close, but the data will be quoted, which may be good enough. If not, you need to research how to output *raw* JSON with Spring.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. I will definitely do that! Thank you